# Download MQseries server version 7.0 for 32 bit windows version

Tags: windows, ibm-mq, 32-bit

I want MQseries server version 7.0 or below version 8.0 for 32 bit window version.

I am not able to find any archives and link to download old version of MSMQseries to use in 32 bit version.

Please provide link of archives and other links to provide information, where do I download MQseries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like it is about server administration rather than programming, and I'm not convinced "where do I download X?" questions are on-topic anyway

Answer (score 1):

MQ 7.0 reached EOL on 30 Apr 2015 so your support options are very limited, consider the 8.0 product which is supported until 2020-04-30.  If you must use 7.0, as it is a licensed product, you'll need to download it from [PassPort Advantage (PPA)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031912)
Consult the appropriate [IBM KnowledgeCenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v70.doc/WelcomePagev7r0.htm) for information on installing usage.